# iOS 8 : how to set height programmatically for a UITableview in a freeform ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

Rookie in iOS.
I have a Freeform ViewController, which has an UIImageView and
UITableView in it.

The Problem i am facing here is when i try to scroll the tableview
some of the items stay hidden because of the height it has taken in the freeform 
viewcontroller.

I tried the following code to set the UItableview's height programmatically 
according to the size of the screen.

```
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    tableview.frame = CGRectMake(0,imageview.frame.height, 280,  (screenSize.height -imageview.frame.height))
```

The above code failed to resize the tableview.

Is there any other way that i can set the UITableview size at Runtime or
in the storyboard.

**Solution**

I resolved the issue after laid out my both views using custom height and width after specifying translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true for both the views. I did as per my design and app requirement.

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: yes @DharmbirSingh i am using AutoLayout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using auto layout or constraints, you have to

```
tableview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
```

before applying the new frame, the new frame is not updating because it's getting over-riden by auto layout and constraints.

**EDIT :**

1- if you have [adjust scroll view insets] enabled in your view controller in story boards disable it, and test and see.

2- do you create the imageView programatically? or from interface builder, and do you have constraints on it?

3- did you know that the status bar has a height and you have to compensate for it too?

4- do you use a navigation bar?

Comment: I did the above before giving a frame to the tableView but now my imageview has been overlapped by the tableview can you suggest something.

Comment: if you post images and details, i think i would be able to help.

Comment: you can see the pic above

Comment: thank you, i resolved the issue after laid out my both views using custom height and width after specifying translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true for both the views

Comment: good, if this solves the problem please mark the answer as accepted, else ask if you still have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is a delegate function for the `UITableViewCell` height.

Here you specify the indexPath of that particular cell and return your height for it

```
(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(indexPath.section == yourSection && indexPath.row == yourRow) {
        return 140.0; //return height for required row
    }
    // "Else"
    return someDefaultHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't set Tableview height programmatically.

Just do one thing

Take Top, Bottom, Leading, Trailing constraints and set constant value to 0

Add user image view into tableview header.